# Trying to parse a a user input and format it as a phone number

Tags: android, string, parsing, android-edittext

I'm trying to parse a user input from an EditText of number type as a phone number but its not being formatted correctly. On the action used to call the number it tells me the number is invalid. Is this code correctly parsing it for the call intent?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PbfSampleApplication.this); 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
EditText innerView = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.number); 
String actualnum="tel:"+innerView.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Well what is the actual "number" being returned from that call to `toString()` ?

Comment: In your Xml file add this attribute to EditText Field android:inputType="number" . Then User can enter integer values only and then you can simply use String.valueOf(innerView)

Comment: This actually got me closest, but now its calling some android widget EditText value instead of the number itself entered. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you trying:

```
String.valueOf(innerView.getText());
```

instead of:

```
toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate mobile number using below code:

```
 private boolean isValidPhone(String s) {
    String expression = "^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$";
    CharSequence inputString = s;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```